# Table not found while creating dataframe from Hive Table

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Spark Command:

```
spark-submit \
--class com.dev.SparkHiveToHdfs \
--jars /home/dev/dbJars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/home/dev/dbJars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/home/dev/dbJars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar \
--master yarn-cluster \
--name DCA_SPARK_JOB \
/home/dev/dbJars/data-connector-spark.jar dev.emp
```

`data-connector-spark.jar` contains below code:

```
public class SparkHiveToHdfs {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String hiveTableNameWithSchema = args[0];

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setMaster("yarn-cluster").setAppName("DCA_HIVE_HDFS");
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    HiveContext hc = new HiveContext(sc);
    DataFrame df = hc.sql("select * from "+hiveTableNameWithSchema);
    df.printSchema();
 }
}
```

Properties in `hive-site.xml` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf`:

```
  <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.client.connect.retry.delay</name>
      <value>5</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout</name>
      <value>1800</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.connect.retries</name>
      <value>24</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
      <value>thrift://xxxx:9083</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
      <value>10000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
      <value>binary</value>
    </property>
```

Error log:

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: `dev`.`emp`; line 1 pos 18
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: `dev`.`emp`; line 1 pos 18
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
    at com.impetus.idw.data.connector.SparkHiveToHdfs.main(SparkHiveToHdfs.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:559)
```

Comment: Please pass the hive-site.xml file in ur  spark-submit using --files option

Comment: Please try: `show databases` in SQL. Then select the database using `use <database>` and then try `show tables` to see what tables you are able to see.

Comment: @RajatMishra is right. When submitting the job as `yarn-cluster`, you have to provide the `hive-site.xml`.

Comment: @RajatMishra I can't add `--files` in my case. It should work if it's under `$SPARK_HOME/conf`. Let me know if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: @devツ no.. actually in cluster mode , we need to specify the hive-site.xml  or u need to manually put the hive-site.xml file in $SPARK_HOME/conf folder at all nodes.

Comment: @RajatMishra Ambari is taking care of it. It's available on all the nodes of the HDP cluster.

Comment: @devツ yeah .. i mean when we pass hive-site.xml with --files , the hive-site.xml is shipped to the all nodes where spark-job is being executed. If its already present on all the node where your job is being executed , then it shouldn't give an error. In our case, we found the hive-site.xml was not present on every node , so on safer side its better to pass in spark-submit job itself.

Comment: @RajatMishra you are right. I manually checked `hive-site.xml` on each node and found it missing on some of the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try passing the hive-site.xml in the spark submit command.

```
spark-submit \
--class com.dev.SparkHiveToHdfs \
--jars /home/dev/dbJars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/home/dev/dbJars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/home/dev/dbJars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar \
--master yarn-cluster \
--name DCA_SPARK_JOB \
--files hive-site.xml
/home/dev/dbJars/data-connector-spark.jar dev.emp
```